# asyncio.gather not working as expected within FastApi

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have a FastApi app running with `uvicorn` for my local dev:

`uvicorn server.app:fapi --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`

I would like to have have 3 couritines running at the same time, but it seems `asyncio.gather()` and/or `await asyncio.sleep(3)` is hanging:

```
async def write_notification(email: str, message=""):
    print(f'Processing message "{message}"')
    await asyncio.sleep(3) # simulate email send
    print('foo after sleep') # <-- This never prints
    return message

async def process_notifications(email: str, message=""):
    tasks = [write_notification(email, f'{message} - {i}') for i in range(3)] # <-- 3 tasks into queue
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(result) # <-- This never prints
    for i in result:
        print(i, 'sent') # <-- This never prints

@app.get('/bg-tasks-multiple', status_code=201)
async def background_tasks(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(process_notifications, email, f"notification for {email}")
    return {'success': True, 'email': email}
```

The only output I get:

```
Processing message "notification for fef@ewf.fgwe - 0"
Processing message "notification for fef@ewf.fgwe - 1"
Processing message "notification for fef@ewf.fgwe - 2"
```

So I know that `write_notification` function is being executed.

Already tried removing `await asyncio.sleep(3)` for debugg and the result is the same, the print on `process_notifications` is never executed, looks like it's hanging somewhere.

Example taken from: [Using several workers in a background task - Fast-API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457574/using-several-workers-in-a-background-task-fast-api)

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)

Comment: Thank you @Chris, didn't really helped me. I already tried with and without `async` on the route itself.

Comment: I also tried your code and it works well.
What Python and FastAPI versions do you use?

Comment: Question: how are you running this code? Locally or on some kind of cloud provider?

Comment: @M.O. Locally, it's my first sentence in the question d:

Comment: @MotovYurii, python 3.10, FastApi 0.85.0

Comment: @Chris actually I tried what you said. It works if I remove `@app.middleware("http")` , not sure what could be the relation, but this middleware has `return await call_next(request)` . If I delete this middleware it works fine.

Comment: @Chris I submited the answer. I didn't provide enough info in the question to reach that conclusion (but didn't imagine it could be cause).

Comment: @Chris I don't see any other reason. The middleware is doing exactly that, just setting up hardcoded lang according to the request header. The fact is that if I delete that middleware the code (all prints) above work as expected.

Comment: @Chris take a look at this: https://streamable.com/34kdee

Comment: @Chris . True and I agree, as I mentioned "Sorry, I didn't provide enough info in the question to reach this conclusion (but didn't imagine this could be cause)." . If you checked the link I sent you can clearly see that was causing the issue, at least for me (don't know the reason),.

PS: I agree/get what you're saying and I can delete the question, it's no problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue was.

Sorry, I didn't provide enough info in the question to reach this conclusion (but didn't imagine this could be cause).

It seems it was caused by this middleware:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def set_language(request: Request, call_next):
    request.state.lang = request.headers.get('X-Lang')
    return await call_next(request)
```

If I delete this block it works fine.

But since I need this block above I opted to use a workaround using `asyncio.create_task` instead of `background_tasks.add_task` which seems to work fine and does what's expected even using the middleware:

```
@app.get('/bg-tasks-multiple', status_code=201)
async def background_tasks(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    asyncio.create_task(process_notifications(email, f"notification for {email}")) # <-- this instead of the line below
    # background_tasks.add_task(process_notifications, email, f"notification for {email}")
    return {'success': True, 'email': email}
```